# Send a variable to other function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple web page in with im using fetch to display some users (i display them as list of cards). Also, every user has a button which navigate to another page in which I want to display  the user's posts (another fetch about posts). 
The prblem is that i should know the id of the user in which i pressed the button in order to display his posts. But how can i get this id?

Here is the fetch code which displays the the list of user cards:

```
function getUsers() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      let output = '<h2 class="mb-4">Users</h2>';
      data.forEach(function(user) {
        output += `
          <div class ="card" style="width:18rem;">
            <div class ="card-body">
              <h5 class ="card-title">Name: ${user.name}</h5>
              <p class ="card-text">Email: ${user.email}</p>
              <input type="button" id="${user.id}"  value="Show posts" onClick="showpost(this.id)">
            </div>
          </div>
        `;
      });
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the line below

```
<input type="button" id="${user.id}"  value="Show posts" onClick="showpost(this.id)">
```

to

```
<input type="button" id="${user.id}"  value="Show posts" onClick="showpost(${user.id})">
```

Now your function showpost should look something like

```
function showpost(userId){
    alert(userId); // Here you get the ID of the user you want to display the posts
}
```

Do the display of posts by extending the function.